# How to use email as username in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to use e-mail id as username in my WooCommerce site. I can see both (username & e-mail ID) in my website I would like to show only email id and password on the registration page. Let me know how to do this.

Comment: This has been default functionality in WooCommerce since 2.2

Comment: Well you say that @Ewout, but I am using Version 2.5.5 and it is using the visitors First Name, not the email address.  Clean install with Storefront and Child Theme.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember where I found it, but I use this on one of my sites. Place it in your theme's functions.php file.

```
/**
 // Allow customers to login with their email address or username
**/
add_filter('authenticate', 'internet_allow_email_login', 20, 3);
/**
 * internet_allow_email_login filter to the authenticate filter hook, to fetch a username based on entered email
 * @param  obj $user
 * @param  string $username [description]
 * @param  string $password [description]
 * @return boolean
 */
function internet_allow_email_login( $user, $username, $password ) {
    if ( is_email( $username ) ) {
        $user = get_user_by_email( $username );
        if ( $user ) $username = $user->user_login;
    }
    return wp_authenticate_username_password( null, $username, $password );
}
?>
```